# How to get windows store app crash logs

Tags: wpf, crash, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-async

I'am developing windows store application. Sometimes application gets hang and crash. In the development environment is there any best way to get crash reports and analyze those reports. I have gone through some articles regarding application crashes. In those they've mentioned about windows application logs and report.wer files. But those files not contained much information about application crash (like stack trace). Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For published apps on Windows Store (metro apps) and Windows Phone, all info about crashes (exceptions) you can get in **Dashboard**, where you submit the application, in **Crash reports** section.

For each application you can download excel file, where you can see all occurred exceptions and stack trace for each exception.

Or you can create your own logging system and submit crash log from user device in automatic mode or let the user to choose.

(Automatic send mode is not recommended, just for option)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sometimes application suddenly crashes. I have used try catch blocks in my application. But didn't catch those exceptions. So any way to log those exceptions.

Comment: Usually in the application projects (WP, WinStore) is automatically created event handler for **UnhandledException** , all occurred exceptions, that were not handled will get in that handler. But some exceptions cannot be catched in try-catch, like an awaitable methods with **void** return type.

Comment: Thank you very much. My app still not published to the WinStore. In my application I have used awaitable methods with void return type. Are there any ways(Best practices) to log those exceptions.

Comment: In C# 5 you can use only one way. About of the best practices async\await programming you can read [here (link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) . Look at **Avoid Async Void** section.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the crash reports from crash window which contains break and continue buttons. It might be applicable when you don't get the stack trace from your code. Now you can close the crash window and the bug line will be highlighted, mousehover on the args of that event and you can find TextVisualizer.
Now open that and you can find the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can i get the crash window in visual studio 2013?